# Add View dialog does not work in an MVC 5 project that references an F# project

Tags: f#, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

1. Using Visual Studio 2013, create a new ASP.NET Web Application project using the MVC template. Verify that the Add View dialog functions by right-clicking the "Views\Home" folder and choosing "Add... View".
2. Now add a new F# Library project to the solution. The Add View dialog should still function correctly.
3. Now add a project reference from the MVC project to the F# project by right-clicking the References folder, choosing Add Reference, Then browse to Solution...Projects on the left and checking the F# library project that you just added.

At this point, if you right-click the "Views\Home" folder and choose "Add... View" you will get an error in a pop-up alert box instead of the Add View dialog:

> There was an error running the selected code generator: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Workarounds include, but are hopefully not limited to:

- Remove all your references to any F# projects every time you want to add a new view.
- Unload any referenced F# projects, but leave the project references in place, every time you want to add a new view.

My questions are:

- Are other people seeing this behavior, or is it just me?
- Does anyone know of a better work-around than removing references or unloading F# projects?
- Does anyone know if Microsoft is already working on fixing this? If not should this be reported to the F# team or the Visual Studio team?

Between this issue and the fact that it is still impossible to use NuGet to add an Entity Framework 6 reference to any F# project, I'm starting to get nervous about Microsoft's level of commitment to the F# language.

Comment: Feel free to vote for the associated bug report... https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/806801/add-view-dialog-does-not-work-in-an-mvc-5-project-that-references-an-f-project

Comment: Might not be an F# issue: this same error mysteriously started happening for me in VS2013 without warning and without any F# projects at all.  If in the context dialog, instead of choosing Add View, I choose Add New Item, then add a View from the New Item dialog, I can add a view.  Maybe some registry setting got corrupted.  The only thing I did that may be causative was add a Unit Test Project

Comment: I have the same issue with F# project. Regarding workaround - every time I need a new view I just copy an existing `.cshtml` file, rename it and delete all content. At least I don't need to remove and re-add the reference to my f# project.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if this will help you but check the version of EntityFramework in your solution. I had two projects within my solution and for whatever reason, the web project had EF 6 and the class library project was EF 6.1. Once I uninstalled EF completely from the solution and reinstalled EF 6.1 on both project, the "Add new view" action started working.

Comment: Yep, this was my problem as well. The project with the EDMX was using EF 6.1.1 and the web project was using EF 6.1.3. After updating everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I received the same error message when adding views or controllers in a C# & MVC multi-project solution, using EF 6.1 and VS2013 with Update 3. The problem was because the nuget "packages" folder was marked as read only, because it was checked into source control. I checked the entire folder out, making it editable, and it started working fine, allowing me to scaffold straight from VS.

I also received the error message in a web.api project because I forgot to add the Entity Framework connection string to the web.config (it was using Areas and EF was looking in the Area web.config, not the web.config in the root).

Comment: It might be related to the MVC post where the error was caused by the missing web.config: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22388052/200824